# Not able to use the break statement

Tags: python, string, break

```
a=str(raw_input('Enter the word \n'))
def back_word(m):
    b=len(m)
    d=b-1
    print m[d]
    if d>0:
        back_word(m)
        d-1
    else:
        break


print back_word(a)
```

My objective is to take a string and print the letters backwards, one in each line. I am getting a break outside loop error. Can anybody correct my code and give a reason for the error?

Comment: `break` uses within **loop** (or `switch` in c, c++), just return

Comment: One extra problem that your code has is that it does not work on empty strings because it will always try to print at least one character. As a rule of thumb its better to check if you are done at the start of the function, not at the end.

Comment: Everyone is telling about `break`, but noone tells a thing about useless `d-1` statement :)

Comment: @LennartRegebro take a look at the very first comment :)

Comment: Thanks everybody! I have now understood when to use break statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the `break` statement.

`break` is used to break out of a **loop**: whether it would be a `while` loop or a `for` loop.

If you want to break out of a function, just use `return`. This is short for `return None`. After a function returns something, it breaks.

```
if d > 0:
    back_word(m)
    d - 1
else:
    return
```

Also, don't expect `d - 1` to do anything :p. If you want to remove 1 from `d`, use `d -= 1`. This is equivalent to `d = d - 1`.

And `raw_input()` returns a string already, so doing `str(raw_input(...` is not needed :).

One last thing, you forgot to slice the string when calling the function recursively. If you don't do this, you will get a `RuntimeError`:

```
if d > 0:
    back_word(m[:-1])
    d -= 1
else:
    return
```

Comment: @LennartRegebro A loop isn't needed. He recursively calls this function.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. My bad. Too early in the morning. No coffee.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the code to print out something like this if a=string, after i run the program the output should be: g n i r t s in separate lines. But this code is printing the last alphabet recursively. What to do?

Comment: @madjavarumours You've actually forgotton a step. When calling `back_word()` in the function, do `back_word(m[:-1])`, otherwise you will get an error

Answer (score 2):

`break` is used to end loops early. `return` is used to end functions early. While the function you're working on is in a way a loop (recursion), the `break` statement is not going to work in this context. You need this:

```
if d>0:
    back_word(m)
    d-1
else:
    return
```

Comment: He's using a recursive function to do that. Currently, his `break` statement is attempting to end the recursive loop. However, that will not work. You didn't read his code very carefully: note that his function `back_word` calls itself iff `d>0`. If `d<=0` then it is supposed to end. `return` is the correct way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the code to print out something like this if a=string, after i run the program the output should be: g n i r t s in separate lines. But this code is printing the last alphabet recursively. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are misunderstanding the break command. It is used to end a loop early. Try this:

```
if d>0:
  back_word(m)
  d-1

else:
  return
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the code to print out something like this if a=string, after i run the program the output should be: g n i r t s in separate lines. But this code is printing the last alphabet recursively. What to do?

Comment: I know another way to do this that just prints out an input red string backwards. Shall I put it in my answer?